# rails game project: ajax requests from model.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i got some kind-of-game rails project with different banana icons in a garden.

- [bananas in garden view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSPCw.jpg)
- [bananas in list view with attributes for debug purposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp9Kz.png)
  the bananas are ripening stepwise and are depicted in the garden view. 
  i got a scheduler.rb as model that updates the banana ripeness attribute in a own thread. the attribute nexttime is for the scheduler to update the ripeness attribute.

so my question is how can i fire a html event from the scheduler.rb so that when the scheduler updates the ripeness attribute of the banana.rb that i get the next-ripe banana icon as ajax in the garden view.
more detail on the code: three classes: banana.rb, scheduler.rb, garden.rb

**garden.rb relations**

```
class Garden < ApplicationRecor
  has_many :bananas, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :scheduler, required: false
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
 def imghelper ripeness
    if ripeness == 0
      # inline_svg "banana-green.svg"
      image_tag "green.png"
    elsif ripeness ==1
      # inline_svg "banana-yellowgreen2.svg"
      image_tag "yellowgreen.png"
    elsif ripeness == 2
      # inline_svg "banana.svg"
      image_tag "yellow.png"
    end
  end
```

**garden/show.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <% rowid = 0%>
  <% @bananas.in_groups_of(@garden.sizex) do |rows| %>
    <tr>
      <% rowid += 1%>
      <% colid = 0%>
      <% rows.each do |b| %>
        <td>
          <% colid += 1%>
          <% tostring = "#{rowid}-#{colid}"%>
          <div id="<%= tostring %>" class="banana">
          <%= imghelper b.ripeness %>
          </div>
        </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: From what I've understood, using `ActionCable` might be a good approach. [This tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/action-cable-and-websockets-an-in-depth-tutorial/) might be useful for you as its quite a similar broadcast event (it broadcasts on create, where as you will want to broadcast on update).